# CollectionView cellForItemAt indexPath does deque cells but cell's view is nil

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as? MYVerticalCell else {
  fatalError("Couldn't deque `Vertical Cell`")
}

cell.view.backgroundColor = .black
return cell
```

view outlet is connected with cell

Throws unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: at which line the code crashes ?

Comment: @Mansi Shahuse control+k to format your code.

Comment: @Mansi Shah is there a UIView in your custom cell class?have you used something in viewDidLoad to register your cell?

Comment: Just checking. Are you sure is Vertical Call and not VerticalCell?

Comment: Check outlet view is properly connected with MYVerticalCell.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have registered my cell from viewDidLoad too.

Comment: @NikunjDamani Crashes where I apply bgColor

Comment: @NiravD I have checked it is connected

Comment: @MansiShah Can you show the screenshot of connection.

Comment: @Mansi Shah are you creating collection view from storyboard or from coding?have you given cell identifiewr from storyboard?

Comment: @NiravD I need more reputation to embed any image

Comment: @TusharSharma xib

Comment: @Mansi Shah havr you given cell identifier from xib as well? If yes then remove (tableview.register) line from (viewDidLoad.)

Comment: @MansiShah, can you show us how did you register the custom cell?

Comment: @x4h1d Solved, I had been registering class instead of nib, was out of my mind may be earlier 

Comment: @TusharSharma I found my mistake, thanks anyway 

Answer (score 2):

First create xib of custom cell with identifier,

Register cell before use, using below example,

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "custCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "custCell")
```

And then use below in "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell"

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custCell") as? CustCell

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = CustCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "custCell"
}
```

Comment: My question was for UICollectionView
Anyway, I have done the same register, and dequeue with collection view cell too.